# How to insert tabs before output lines from a executed command

Tags: command-line, bash

Just a quick question. Is it possible to tab the output on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? I've created two images below to try and illustrate what I mean by this.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: Would it be okay if you have to pipe the command output through another command like `YOUR COMMAND | indent` or if you have to type another command in front of it (could even be only an underscore) like `_ YOUR COMMAND`?

Comment: @ByteCommander I have considered that, however I'm doing this for ease of use and to make console output easier to read. So I don't think piping my all of my commands is the solution. Thank you for the response and edit though!

Comment: [Please don't post screeshots of text output. ](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do something like this - with file descriptors:

1. save the current output descriptor so we can restore it later

   ```
   exec 3>&1
   ```
2. redirect the output stream to a *process substitution* that inserts the tab - for example

   ```
   exec 1> >(paste /dev/null -)
   ```

From this point, any process that writes to standard output will have that output 'filtered' through the `paste` command to insert tabs at the start.

3. When you're done, you can resume normal behavior by restoring the saved file descriptor and closing the temporary one

   ```
   exec 1>&3 3>&-
   ```

Comment: I'd like to thank you for the response. This is the closest I've come to a solution even though it's not perfect.

Comment: @AlexNg thanks for the upvote - in what way specifically doesn't it do what you asked for? if you let me know I will try to improve it

Comment: To give a few examples: After inputting your commands, some commands do work as intended such as 'php -v', 'hostname' and others. However, when using a command such as 'echo Hello World', the output is displayed inline with the input and it also adversely effects the input visual appearance  when inputting the next command. Some other commands are also no effected by the tabbing process, such as when inputting an invalid command such as 'asdasd'.

Comment: Finally, it does not correctly display output that changes (not sure how to describe this properly, apologies). For example, if the command 'apt-get update' is used, there are noticeable differences when comparing it to a console without the tabbing process.

Comment: The problem is that this approach only handles STDOUT (stream 1), but not STDERR (stream 2). It does also break the output of programs that use `less` or similar tools to allow scrolling of the output, like e.g. `man`.

Answer (score 12):

I understand this answer is not optimal for you, but you could make a Bash function with the simple name like `_` (or anything else that is not used yet) which runs the command it gets as arguments and indents all of its output with a tab.

An example:

```
$ _ lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
    Release:    16.04
    Codename:   xenial
```

More complex shell constructs would be possible too, but need to be given as quoted argument or with special characters escaped to prevent evaluation before it was passed to the function.

```
$ _ 'for x in {1..3} ; do echo $x ; done'
    1
    2
    3

$ _ for x in \{1..3\} \; do echo \$x \; done
    1
    2
    3
```

---

The code for this function would only be this:

```
_(){ eval "$@" |& sed "s/^/\t/" ; return "$PIPESTATUS" ;}
```

As a side effect, this would merge STDERR into STDOUT in order to indent both, but on the other hand it also preserves the exit status of the given command.

You can append this line above to your `~/.bashrc` file so that it will be available in all Bash sessions of your user.

---

<sub>The previous version of this answer suggested the function below, but that would not indent STDERR streams and also suppress return/exit codes in case the given command fails. Besides, it would have broken commands with quotes or significant whitespace due to the bad `$*` variable expansion instead of `"$@"`, and probably there were even more problems...</sub>

```
_(){ sed "s/^/\t/" <($*); }
```

Comment: This works very well, but it swallows return values, so if used in a script with `set -x` the script will carry on despite errors. Is there a way to have it return the value that the inner command returned?

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the poke, that made me revise my answer from almost 4 years ago and realize how terrible it was what have written back then ;D So anyway, I refactored my answer now to take exit status into account, and fixed a few other problems as well.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about pipestatus - should it be $PIPESTATUS[0] ?

Comment: @Michael correctly it would be `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` to access it as an array properly, but if you just use the plain name of the array variable like I did, it expands to the first array element too, so those are equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

With `echo` specifically, you can have it interpret backslash escapes like `\t` (a [tab stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop)) with the `-e` switch:

```
echo -e "\tHello World"
```

But it would hardly be feasible (or probably possible) to modify the output the of every command that way. If ease of read is your goal, you might want to look into customizing the look (e. g. the coloring) of your command prompt, like shown here:

[image]

You can customize your prompt by changing the content of the environment variable `PS1`. You can see a little example of how to do that in the [blog post](http://lcorg.blogspot.de/2010/02/prompt-tricks.html) the above screenshot is from. How to use those so called ANSI escape sequences in detail, how to use tools that are more comfortable, how to have the changes applied by default in new terminals etc. are beyond the scope of this answer. But if you decide to use that technique, there are a lot of tutorials and further information around the web.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I've already changed PS1 to my liking.

Answer (score 2):

I found an easier way:

```
your-command | paste /dev/null -
```

From `man paste.1`:

> Write  lines  consisting  of the sequentially corresponding lines from
> each FILE, separated by TABs, to standard output.